# Как в CLion переключить стиль на ANSI?

Tags: c++, windows, ide, clion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут включил всё и поставил скобки у else нажал ENTER.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё тоже самое, но всё выключено.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в CLion переключить стиль на ANSI?

В ANSI фигурные скобки отображаются не вот так, а сразу переносятся на следующую строчку
[image: Там фигурные скобки отображаются не вот так, а сразу переносятся на следующую строчку]

Знаете что это и зачем нужно?

[image: Знаете что это и зачем нужно?]

Comment: поищи про clang-format, там можно много чего настроить под себя

Answer (score 1):

Насчет форматирования: нужно переключить стиль K&R (это скобки на той же линии в конце) на ANSI в Predefined Style:

для Windows и Linux: File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | C/C+

для macOS: CLion | Preferences | Editor | Code Style | C/C++

Насчет Line Separator: в UNIX и Linux строки заканчиваются символом `'\n'` (new line), а в Windows двумя символами `"\r\n"` (carriage return, new line). Можно выставить в опциях System-Dependent, чтобы заканчивал символами по умолчанию (если IDE на Windows - как для Windows, если на Linux - как для Linux).

Comment: Я отредактировал пост посмотри пожалуйста
@AndreyBelkin

Comment: @Someone_69 там или Scheme наверху или wrapping and braces закладка

Comment: Я отредактировал пост. Это всё что есть, но я не вижу данного пункта.

Comment: Во всех подпунктах Braces placement надо переключить на new line

Comment: Да вороде ничего не поменялось или я чего-то не понимаю (скрины выше) @AndreyBelkin